# I am having an error with big query using concat syntax error expected end of input but got identifier count at [1:77]

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, concatenation

```
SELECT usertype
, CONCAT(start_station_name,"to", end_station_name) AS route 
  COUNT(*) AS num_trips
, ROUND(AVG(CAST(tripduration as int64)/60),2) as duration 
FROM `bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_trips` 
GROUP BY start_station_name, end_station_name, usertype 
order by num_trips DESC LIMIT 10
```

Comment: missing comma before count

Comment: Please describe better your question in testual form, not just in the title

Answer (score 1):

There is a missing comma between 'as route`and`COUNT(*)`.